# Intellij doesn't show .git directory

Tags: intellij-idea

How I can I get Intellij to show the .git folder in the project viewer?  I tried ctrl+alt+A and clicked "show hidden files and directories", but it doesn't switch to the "on" position, so I suppose that's not the way of going about this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Maybe try turning off the git integration?

Comment: Git integration is great, sometimes you just want to edit the .git/config file quickly though

Comment: @ChrisKitching `.git/hooks` is somewhere I'd like to be able to edit stuff easily with the benefits of an IDE.

Comment: Or, you are using some interesting tool like git filter-repo that outputs the report to .git/filter-repo. There are just so many cases where being able to toggle this on and off would be great.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The .git directory is ignored by default. To see it in the project pane, do the following:

- Go to the settings (`Help | Find Action...`<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and type "Settings").
- Navigate to `Editor | File Types` in the Settings dialog.
- Remove `.git` from the table under the `Ignored files and folders` tab.

[image]

Comment: On Mac, to bring the settings up ⌘-,  (cmd-comma) works best.

Comment: On IDEA 2022.2 `Ignored Files and Folders` is on a tab next to `Recognized File Types`

Comment: @gerrytan thanks, I have updated my answer for this changed UI.